# convert binary to decimal

Tags: haskell

```
selectMenu :: Int->IO() 
selectMenu num
        |(num==2)=convertBinToDecimal



convertBinToDecimal:: IO()
convertBinToDecimal= do 
            putStrLn("\n\tConvert Binary To Decimal\n")
            putStrLn("----------------------------------------------------------\n")
            putStrLn("Enter 5 binary numbers [,,] : ") 
            input<-getLine
            let n=(read input)::Int
            --putStrLn (show n)
            let result = convertionTO binaryToDec n
            putStrLn(show result)
```

this code seems fine.but there is an error.

Any solutions to fix this error?
Thank you

Comment: The way you write `putStrLn("Foo")` is kinda odd. It's much more common to write a function `f` applied to `x` as `f x`, so in your case `putStrLn "Foo"` is a lot more natural.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use `reverse` on `x`, which is an `Int` (since it's the argument of `binaryToDec`, which you have given the type `Int -> Int`), but `reverse` has the type `[a] -> [a]`, so it only works on lists.

This is basically what the compiler means when it says "cannot match expected type `[a]` with actual type `Int` in the first argument of `reverse`". It's a good idea to read the error messages carefully, they often provide good clues to what is wrong.

To fix this, you probably want to convert `x` to a list somehow, or change the function to take a list instead.

Comment: Know of an existing function to do that? I know that `map digitToInt $ show x` works, but seems kind of hackish.

Comment: @Pubby: Nothing in the standard libraries. There's a [digits package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/digits/0.2/doc/html/Data-Digits.html) on Hackage, though.

Answer (score 1):

Like hammar said you cannot reverse `Int`. You need to convert your number to list somehow with `:: Int -> [Int]`

Here is some kludges to do that.

```
listToNum :: [Int] -> Int
listToNum = foldl1 ( (+) . (*10) )

numToList :: Int -> [Int] 
numToList n | n <= 9    = [n]
            | otherwise = numToList (n `div` 10) ++ [n `mod` 10]
```

And then you can use it like `reverse $ numToList x` instead of `reverse x`.

And just a note. Your `selectmenu` function did not matches all possible cases. What if `num` is not equal to 2?

Comment: ah yeah. Other parts of this program is on the way. (hint: still writing)